# Implementing third-party API with CakePHP 3

Tags: php, api, cakephp-3.0, message360

I'm trying to build an web application that enables users to input a due date for any subscription or service. When the user adds a service, he/she is able to submit a method of contact that will happen on the day of the due date. The various methods are either an SMS, Phone calls, and Emails. 
The API I'm using is called Message360. Some more information can be found on the API through this link:

http://ytel-inc.github.io/Message360-PHP-Helper-Library/

I'm relatively new to CakePHP as I've only worked with CodeIgniter. 
An account for using the API is required and I have one. 
Would anyone have some tips on how to make my application listen for all the users' due dates and send out a text, email, etc., based on their preffered method of contact?

The biggest issue here is I'm not completely certain on how to implement a third-party API with Cake and I've read through the documentation provided.

Another issue would be getting the data and making my application constantly watch for an event such as a due date and then calling that request to the Message360 API server to make a text, phone call, or email.

Would I have to copy the PHP library into my CakeApp library folder and then make a separate controller for it? Or would it be more plausible to put it into my AppController.

Any words of wisdom would be greatly appreciated. I will also link lines of code from my application if that would help.

Answer (score 1):

> The biggest issue here is I'm not completely certain on how to implement a third-party API with Cake and I've read through the documentation provided.

1. Put your Message360 Lib in **/vendor** - *We will use **/vendor/Message360** in this example*
2. Include it using

   `require_once(ROOT . 'vendor' . DS  . 'Message360' . DS . 'library' . DS . 'message360.php');`
3. Include class name

   `namespace App\Controller;
   use Message360;
   use Message360_Exception;`
4. Use Message360 in your application :)

   `$Message360 = Message360::getInstance();`
5. You can find more examples from here

   https://github.com/Ytel-Inc/Message360-PHP-Helper-Library
6. If that doesn't work, you can always get support from **support@message360.com**

> Another issue would be getting the data and making my application constantly watch for an event such as a due date and then calling that request to the Message360 API server to make a text, phone call, or email.

- You can use cronjob
  http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html
- You can also use online server like www.easycron.com. Create a controller and a method and let easycron hit the url of your method.